# hi,mongodb c# driver Cannot read the slave,so I had a bad day

Tags: mongodb

this is Log txt

`error:[_47Baby.DBModule.Fun1.FunDB2.InserPlayer]Safemode detected an error 'not master'. (Response was { "err" : "not master", "code" : 10054, "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 7, "ok" : 1.0 }).`

The setup is 1 master, and 2 slaves.

One of the slave read is success,but another slave is error, the message is Safemode detected an error 'not master'.

I have already setting the server string "mongodb://********/databasename?safe=true;slaveok=true"

Answer (score 1):

What driver method did you call when you got this exception? Not all operations are able to be  sent to a slave.

Are you putting a single hostname on your connection string (the "**" part)? Or are you putting a seedlist with multiple members of the replica set?

If you can provide a stack trace that would be helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB v2.2, it now allows another method of allowing reads from slaves/secondary, which allows you to have more control on what happens. See [Read Preferences](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference-modes).

So, this may be of interest to you and might work better than using the server string parameters.

(The follow is an example for the Java driver, but it should be close enough for C#)

The basis of this new method is passing in a type `ReadPreference` into the DBCursor that you use to query the database.

```
ReadPreference preference = ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred();
DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(collection, query, null, preference);
```

Source: [Read Preference Modes¶](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#read-preference-modes)